# Require duration element when deserializing to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, timespan

this is my first question on stack overflow. So my apologies for any wrongdoings from my side!

I have to deserialize some XML, one of the elements is required and of data type xs:duration. How to do this for optional elements can be found at http://kennethxu.blogspot.nl/2008/09/xmlserializer-doesn-serialize-timespan.html, which I used to construct:

```
public class ValueWeightTime
{
    private TimeSpan _value = new TimeSpan();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }

    [Required] //ToDo: fix default value PT0S
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", DataType = "duration")]
    public string XmlValue
    {
        get { return XmlConvert.ToString(_value); }
        set { _value = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value); }
    }
}
```

The Required attribute does not work. Would anyone know how to make the "Value" element required?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
```

If that doesn't work you could do this:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public TimeSpan Value 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlValue))
            throw new AgrumentException("Value is required.");
        return _value; 
    }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thnx for your reply! Unfortunately it didn't work. I still get the default TimeSpans ({00:00:00}) instead of an error.

Comment: Hi Tony, thnx for your edit! 
Unfortunately this still doesn't work. The getter of XmlValue is called, and since the TimeSpan _value is initialized, the XmlValue getter returns "PT0S". So the good news is that this definitely would work if _value would be a nullable/could be initialized with a null value. I tried to do so, but couldn't make the XmlConvert-methods work :( 
Do you have any suggestions?